# get the MAC address of the closest WiFi using Android

Tags: android

Q/ Write an Android program to get the `MAC address` of the closest `WiFi` Access Point

is there any ready written program i can use ?

dose any body have information that might help me ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

See this:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults%28%29)

The `BSSID` is the MAC address of the AP.

Comment: BSSID is not the MAC address of the AP, it is the MAC address of the ssid. Detailed explanation can be found in https://arubanetworkskb.secure.force.com/pkb/articles/FAQ/How-is-the-BSSID-derived-from-the-Access-Point-ethernet-MAC-address